# Binning by days of the week. Pandas Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DF series days of the week.

```
dayname
MONDAY  
MONDAY  
WEDNESDAY 
SATURDAY
SUNDAY
```

What I want to do is plot their counts which I can get using a groupby count function like this `df = df.groupby('dayname').count()` .

```
               count
dayname
MONDAY          2
WEDNESDAY       1 
SATURDAY        1
SUNDAY          1
```

On the plot I would like to show all days of the week even if their value is 0. Similar to the plot below where there is no activity on Saturday but there is still a bar. My current plots only show the data in the DF, (shockingly). So any ideas how I add in the zero values? I had a look at `pd.cut` function for binning but it appears to only assign numerical bins that can be labled. Perhaps I haven't understood it.

[image]

UPDATE

working code per the comments.

This is the dataframe

```
              dayname
startdate
2015-12-13  SUNDAY
2015-12-28  MONDAY
2015-12-14  MONDAY
2015-12-10  THURSDAY
2015-12-20  SUNDAY
```

RESULT OF `df.info()`

```
Index: 30 entries, 2015-12-13 to 2015-12-09
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dayname    30 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

---

```
df = df.dayname.value_counts()
```

CODE RESULT

```
SUNDAY       6
MONDAY       5
WEDNESDAY    4
THURSDAY     4
FRIDAY       4
Name: dayname, dtype: int64
```

SUGGESTED CODE

```
DAYS = ['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']
df = df.reindex(DAYS, fill_value=0)
```

CODE RESULT

```
MONDAY       0
TUESDAY      0
WEDNESDAY    4
THURSDAY     0
FRIDAY       0
Name: dayname, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of days and use it to `reindex`

```
DAYS = ['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']

df.dayname.value_counts().reindex(DAYS, fill_value=0).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm getting a few problems, myreindex command only adds in equal to the amount of rows in the value counts. So for example using the original question data it would only create an index with monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, sorry.  In general, it's far easier to debug things like this when you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example.  This would enable me to copy and past the code you used to generate the example and be more assured that we are looking at the same thing.  Right now, we have to investigate what the problem might be.  I suggest you update you post with such an example.  Link ---> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I edited my question to provide the results of `df.head, df.info` and your code sample results. Hopefully that provides some kind of clarity?